# googleVis does not work properly with two dependent widget shiny

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis

I try to implement a simple shiny app with two dependent widgets.At first everything works fine but a problem occurs when I change a continent value i.e. a map disappears. Do you know what I should add to avoid this obstacle?

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

        sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                        selectInput("continent", "Select the continent: ",
                                    c("Africa", "America", "Asia","Europe"),
                                      selected = "Africa"),
                                      uiOutput('server_country')
                        ),

                                      mainPanel(
                                      htmlOutput("map"))
                        )
        ))
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)

continent_countries <- list(Africa = c("Tunisia"),
                            America = c("Argentina","Brazil"),
                            Asia = c("China","Japan","India"),
                            Europe = c("France","Germany","Italy","Spain"))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

        output$server_country <- renderUI({
                choosen_countries <- input$continent
                selectizeInput('out_country', "Select the countries:",
                               choices = continent_countries[[choosen_countries]])
        })

        continent_code <- reactive({
                switch(input$continent,
                       Africa = "002",
                       America = "019",
                       Asia = "142",
                       Europe = "150")
        })

        output$map <- renderGvis({
                if(is.null(input$out_country))
                        return()
                validate(
                        need(length(input$out_country) > 0, "Please select at least onecountry"))
                #                 
                plot.dataset <- data.frame(countries = input$out_country, value = 5)

                gvisGeoChart(plot.dataset, locationvar = "countries",sizevar = "value",
                             options = list(region = continent_code(),displayMode = "regions"))

        })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to insert a sleep before your gvisGeoChart call like this:

```
Sys.sleep(0.3)

gvisGeoChart(plot.dataset, locationvar = "countries",sizevar = "value",
             options = list(region = continent_code(),displayMode = "regions"))
```

I got it to work like that. This is (probably) because you are falling through the `renderGvis` code twice, and thus actually hitting the Google server twice, once when you change the `continent_code`, and then again when you change the `out_country` control afterwards. Google seemingly doesn't like being hit twice in rapid succession.

I figured that out with print statements and by stumbling across this post:
[Shiny googleVis GeoChart not displaying with reactive switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33530066/shiny-googlevis-geochart-not-displaying-with-reactive-switch/33545225#33545225).

The link mentioned above figured out the solution without seeming to know the cause of the problem.

Here is the graphics so as to better understand the issue:

[image]

Comment: There is probably a way to get it to only hit the server once, but I wouldn't worry too hard about it.

Comment: Yes, but it is not the case here. I want to use concept of input updates, two dependent widgets.

Comment: What is not the case here? It was definitely hitting the server twice. When I added the delay it worked fine.

Comment: You're right. As I understand correctly, you suggest to change ui.R in order to  hit the server once. It is obvious that it is happened twice, because the map shows up twice: firstly without any country, secondly with chosen country.

Comment: Actually I think you would need to modify the server code, so that it only hits the Google server when it has a valid country for the continent.